# Click to Expand a <div> but hover away to back in Normal size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `<div>` which expands when clicking on it and again click to it  back in normal size which is fine BUT I am wanting to have Something like ...

When click on the `<div>` (class name .topHead) it should expand and return to normal size if the cursor is moved from the `<div>` without the need to click to bring it back to the normal size

Is this possible? Any solution will be appreciated.

js Fiddle : **http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/u6YWZ/**

**HTML**

```
<div class="topHead" ></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.topHead {
 height: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #fa9a37;
 z-index: 999;
 transition: all 1.1s ease;
 cursor:pointer;

 }

.topHead.active {
 height: 100px;
 z-index: 999;
 background: blue;
 border-bottom: 6px solid #fa9a37;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px gray;
 cursor:default;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".topHead").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(".TopsliderArrow").toggle();        

        });
```

Comment: what is going on with your caps.

Comment: mouseout mouseleave ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(".topHead").click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass("active");
}).mouseout(function(){
 !$(this).hasClass("active")||($(this).toggleClass("active")/*,...*/);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6YWZ/2/

Comment: I see one Problem . IF there is any text or something inside the .topHeader div and he mouse move to that text the .topheader  goes back to original size .

Comment: yes... as you move the mouse out of that element. if there is just a text it works... if you place other elements inside not

Comment: so add just a text without h1 or span .. and a background image. and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".topHead").on("mouseout",function() { // you may use mouseleave as well instead of mouseout
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(".TopsliderArrow").hide();  // Not Sure what this does but I guess you may hide this      

        });
```

Add this to your js

Comment: it should be `removeClass`, not `remove`.

Comment: Sure! that was a typo on my end

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'd be worried about getting the active class and TopsliderArrow visibility out of sync using `toggle()`. This method doesn't use toggle so *may* better suit your needs.</strike>

```
$(".topHead")
    .on("click",function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(".TopsliderArrow").hide();
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".TopsliderArrow").show();
        }       
    })
    .on("mouseout",function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(".TopsliderArrow").hide();
    });
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6YWZ/1/)

**UPDATE:**

Turns out toggle() works just fine:

```
$(".topHead")
    .on("click",function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".TopsliderArrow").toggle();      
    })
    .on("mouseout",function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(".TopsliderArrow").hide();
    });
```

[Working Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6YWZ/3/)